# Extract ETS method used for automatic forecasts of hierarchical time series with hts package

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to extract the ETS method that is automatically chosen when we apply the *forecast* function to an hierarchical time series using the *hts* R package.

When I look in the structure of the object returned, I can't seen to find it. Does anyone knows if this information is stored in this particular case?

Answer (score 2):

A different ETS model is applied to each node of the hierarchy. The ETS models are not stored in the object returned.

Comment: Thanks Hyndman. Do you know any workarounds that I could use to obtain the method (eg. ANA) that was used for each particular node?

Comment: Run ets on the data for each node.